# Python: Parse multiple datatypes using argparse

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I tried using argparse to learn how it works to parse a given list:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('--ls', nargs='*', type=str, default = [])
Out[92]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--ls'], dest='ls', nargs='*', const=None, default=[], type=<type 'str'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

args = parser.parse_args("--ls 'tomato' 'jug' 'andes'".split())

args
Out[94]: Namespace(ls=["'tomato'", "'jug'", "'andes'"])

args.ls
Out[96]: ["'tomato'", "'jug'", "'ande'"]

args.ls[0]
Out[97]: "'tomato'"

eval(args.ls[0])
Out[98]: 'tomato'
```

Q1: The above works but Is there a better way to access values in the list?

Then I tried it with dictionary to parse a dictionary given:

```
dict_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
dict_parser.add_argument('--dict', nargs='*',type=dict,default={})

Out[104]: _StoreAction(option_strings=['--dict'], dest='dict', nargs='*', const=None, default={}, type=<type 'dict'>, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)

arg2 = dict_parser.parse_args("--dict {'name':'man', 'address': 'kac', 'tags':'don'}")
usage: -c [-h] [--dict [DICT [DICT ...]]]
-c: error: unrecognized arguments: - - d i c t   { ' n a m e ' : ' m a n' ,   ' a d d r e s s ' :   ' k a c' ,   ' t a g s ' : ' d o n ' }
To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit: 2
```

And that doesn't work.
Q2: How does the above work for dictionary?

Q3: Now I want

```
python my.py --ls tomato jug andes  --dict {'name':'man', 'address': 'kac', 'tags':'don'}
```

to be parsed

How do I do that?

I referred to http://parezcoydigo.wordpress.com/2012/08/04/from-argparse-to-dictionary-in-python-2-7/

...and found assigning everything under a dictionary is pretty useful. Could somebody simplify this task so as to parse multiple datatypes in the arguments?

Comment: Q1: what do you want? You get exactly the arguments you put, *including* the quotation marks. If you don't want that, don't surround the arguments with quotation marks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/converting-a-string-to-dictionary

Comment: Q2: you confuse Python and the shell. The arguments are normally given on the shell, and that doesn't hold any idea of a Python dictionary. Hence, you can't create a Python dictionary through arguments, and, in fact, you shouldn't even try. Just make each key a separate option and use it as such.

Comment: @Evert you mean "--ls tomato jug andes" ??

Comment: Note that this appears to me as a very unconventional way of using options. What's wrong with `python my.py --ls tomato jug andes --name man --address kac --tags don`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> parser.add_argument('--ls', nargs='*', type=str, default = [])
>   Q1: The above works but Is there a better way to access values in the list?

As I often consider "simpler is better", and this is a really simple way to do things, I'd say there is no better way. But still, there are other ways.

> dict_parser.add_argument('--dict', nargs='*',type=dict,default={})
>   arg2 = dict_parser.parse_args("--dict {'name':'man', 'address': 'kac', 'tags':'don'}")
>   Q2: How does the above work for dictionary?

I'd advice you to parse your string using json:

```
>>> class FromJSON():
...     def __init__(self, string):
...         self.string = string
...     def decode(self):
...         return json.loads(self.string)
...    
>>> dict_parser.add_argument('--dict',type=FromJSON)
>>> arg2 = dict_parser.parse_args(['--dict', '{"name":"man", "address": "kac", "tags":"don"}'])
```

though JSON is a lot like python, it is not python. It is picky about quoting (values are surrounded by *double quotes* only) and about (*having no*) trailing commas. But at least it is safe against code injection! And of course you shall surround your parameter with quotes

You may have anoter solution to give a dict as parameters, it would be to get rid of the brackets:

```
>>> parser.add_argument('--dict', nargs='*', type=str, default = [])
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--dict', 'name:man', 'address:kac', 'tags:don'])
>>> args.dict = dict([arg.split(':') for arg in args.dict])
>>> print args.dict
{'tags': 'don', 'name': 'man', 'address': 'kac'}
```

Q3: Now I want

```
python my.py --ls tomato jug andes  --dict {'name':'man', 'address': 'kac', 'tags':'don'}
```

to be parsed

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--dict', type=FromJSON, default=FromJSON("{}"))
>>> parser.add_argument('--ls', nargs='*', type=str, default = [])
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--ls', 'tomato', 'jug', 'andes', '--dict', '{"name":"man", "address": "kac", "tags":"don"}'])
>>> args.ls
['tomato', 'jug', 'andes']
>>> args.dict
<__main__.FromJSON instance at 0x7f932dd20c20>
>>> args.dict.decode()
{u'tags': u'don', u'name': u'man', u'address': u'kac'}
```

About `FromJSON()`, it can be improved so it is something like:

```
class JsonToDict():
    def __call__(self, string):
        return json.loads(string)
```

that you could use as follows:

```
dict_parser.add_argument('--dict',type=JsonToDict())
```

HTH

Comment: this is the amazing side of python.yes il look into json as well.works for me.thanks

Comment: so there instead of 3 methods to Json should I use JsonToDict?

Comment: hey, args = parser.parse_args(['--ls', 'tomato', 'jug', 'andes', '--dict', '{"name":"man", "address": "kac", "tags":"don"}']) ; with this                  eval(''.join(args.dict))     works as well. just saying not to write additional classes for it

Comment: Using `eval()` with user input is like f*cking with a stranger without a condom! DO **NEVER EVER** USE `eval()` WITH CODE THAT A USER INPUTS, you can get serious security issues. There's always another better way to do the job that has close to no security flaws. There may be good uses of `eval()` in python, but I still haven't seen one.

Answer (score -1):

```
import ast
dict_parser.add_argument('--dict', nargs='*',type=ast.literal_eval,default={})
args = dict_parser.parse_args(["--dict", "{'name':'man', 'address': 'kac', 'tags':'don'}"])
```

Comment: This will evaluate anything you pass as an argument though, so use at your own risks